# Delphi Firemonkey virtual keyboard is blocking the edit box (Mobile)

Tags: android, delphi, mobile, firemonkey

Delphi Firemonkey Fullscreen Edit

I develop mobile app and has several edit box in it. My problem is when i type to the edit box. the Virtual keyboard blocks the box that i cannot see what i am typing in.

Is there any edit properties to change to make it full-screen editing? like Only edit box and virtual keyboard can be seen. or any suggestion.

Comment: This might help: https://www.delphiworlds.com/2018/07/moving-controls-virtual-keyboard-revisited-again/

Comment: @DaveNottage That page appears to be broken.

Comment: @nolaspeaker Works fine here. Even cleared my cache to make sure. What are you seeing?

Comment: @DaveNottage - This is what I get with your link:  Your connection is not secure

The owner of www.delphiworlds.com has configured their website improperly. To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website.

Comment: Can you try it now?

Comment: @DaveNottage works fine in Edge

Comment: @DaveNottage The screenshot doesn't show (using Firefox here)

Comment: Screenshot shows OK here on Firefox 65.0.1 (macOS)

Answer (score 0):

look at the multidevice samples and you find a demo for that problem.

Comment: Multidevice samples where, and which demo exactly?

Comment: found it - it's the `ScrollableForm` sample under `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\User Interface\ScrollableForm`. Replace "22.0" with your Delphi version number.

Answer (score 0):

this is the fullpath and make sur you installed samples befor or go to github and search
http://sourceforge.net/projects/radstudiodocdem/

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably late answering this. But this is just in case someone needs it.
To fix this issue, set property CONTROL TYPE of your edit or input to Platform instead of styled.

```
Edit1.ControlType := TControlType.Platform;
```